# There is vacant space in my navbar. I want to push the search bar to extreme right what can be done

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: My nvbar according to bootstrap columns]

This is my code of the navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm fixed-top navbar-custom" id="header-nav">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="./index.html"><h2 class="tagline">Subh</h2></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-sm-6" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./index.html"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span>Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></span> Login</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-lg"></i> Cart</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-5 col-sm-4 ml-auto">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></span>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

As you can see in the picture I have marked the vacant space and you see my search bar in center I want to push it to the right but if I increase col-sm-4 to col-sm-5 or put an offset search bar goes to next line which I do not want.

What can be done for this? You see other columns marked by white border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here,

class="navbar-brand mr-auto"

Change Mr-auto to ml-auto

Comment: see if I change the navbar-brand mr-auto to ml-auto then only the brand name will be shifted but I want tto shift only the search bar

Answer (score 0):

It can be placed in the extreme right position, if you specify the float propertty of css...

```
.col-5 col-sm-4 ml-auto {
  float: right;
}
```

or you can specify its right margin to be zero as given below-

```
.col-5 col-sm-4 ml-auto {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

it will solve the problem I guess...

Greetings,
Om Chaudhary